# How do I Run Docker cmds Exactly Like in a Dockerfile

Tags: bash, shell, docker, dockerfile, interactive

There seems to be a difference between how Docker runs commands in a Dockerfile versus running commands manually after starting a container.  This seems to be due to the kind of shells you can start, a (I assume) non-interactive shell with a Dockerfile vs an interactive one when running something like `docker run -it <some-img-id>`.

How can I debug running commands in a Docker container so that it runs exactly like the commands are run from a Dockerfile? Would just adding `/bin/bash --noprofile` to the `run` cmd suffice? Or is there anything else different about the environment when started from a Dockerfile?

Comment: There isn't a generic answer to this -- we'd need to see the **specific** command you're asking about. A [mcve] showing others how to see the difference for themselves would be helpful as well.

Comment: ...commands like `COPY` are implemented completely internal to Docker -- they don't call through to a shell at all. And `RUN` and kin have various modes -- if you pass a literal argument list as an array, again, no shell anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is the behavior because of the shell. Most of us are used to using the bash shell. So generally we would attempt to run the commands in the below fashion

**For new container**

```
docker run -it <imageid> bash
```

**For existing container**

```
docker exec -it <containerid> bash
```

But when we specify some command using `RUN` directive inside a Dockerfile

```
RUN echo Testing
```

Then it is equivalent to running `/bin/sh -c 'echo Testing'`. So you can expect certain differences as both the shells are different.

In Docker 1.12 or higher you have a Dockerfile directive named `SHELL` this allows you to override the default `SHELL`

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN echo Testing
```

This would make the `RUN` command be executed as `bash -c 'echo Testing'`. You can learn more about the `SHELL` directive [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer 1:**

If Dockerfile don't use `USER` and `SHELL` commands, then this:

```
docker --entrypoint "/bin/sh -c" -u root <image> cmd
```

**Short answer 2:**

If you don't squash or compress image after the build, Docker creates images layers for each of the Dockerfile commands. You can see them in the output of `docker build` at the end of each step with `--->`:

```
Step 2/8 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
  ---> 5a5964bed25d # <== THIS IS IMAGE ID OF STEP 2
Removing intermediate container b2bc9558e499
Step 3/8 : RUN something
  ---> f6e90f0a06e2 # <== THIS IS IMAGE ID OF STEP 3
Removing intermediate container b2bc9558e499
```

Look for the image id just before the RUN step you want to debug (for example you want to debug step 3 on above, take the step 2 image id). Then just run the command in that image:

```
docker run -it 5a5964bed25d cmd
```

**Long answer 1:**

When you run `docker run [image] cmd` Docker in fact starts the `cmd` in this way:

- Executes the default entrypoint of the image with the `cmd` as its argument. Entrypoint is stored in the image on build by `ENTRYPOINT` command in Dockerfile. Ie if `cmd` is `my-app` and entrypoint is `/bin/sh -c`, it executes `/bin/sh -c my-app`.
- Starts it with default user id of the image, which is defined by the last `USER` command in Dockerfile
- Starts it with the environment variables from all `ENV` commands from image's Dockerfile commulative

When `docker build` runs the Dockerfile `RUN`, it does exatly the same, only with the values present at that time (line) of the Dockerfile.

So to be exact, you have to take the value of ENVs and last USER command before your RUN line, and use those in the `docker run` command.

Most common images have `/bin/sh -c` or `/bin/bash -c` as entrypoint and most likely the build operates with root user. Therefore `docker --entrypoint "/bin/bash -c" -u root <image> cmd` should be sufficient