# Docker RUN instruction: save result to file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-run

How can I save the result of the `RUN` instruction to a file?

Dockerfile example:

```
# code removed for simplicity

# <--- not working, probably because RUN creates a new layer?
RUN tree -a > public/tree.txt 

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "publish/MyApp.AspNetCore.dll"]
```

Comment: Could you please describe the problem you are trying to solve? The specified command writes the result into a file IN the container. This file exists in the image afterwards and would be accessible for the dotnet application. Writing the file back to the host is not supported though.

Comment: I am manipulating folder contents inside the docker container, and I am using the tree command for debugging purposes. Ideally for me it would be to be able to run the `tree` command multiple times and save the output to external path (using volumes)

Comment: Dockerfiles never access volumes; they can't write back to the host system; they can't make calls to other containers.  All of these things need to be done in your application code, inside the `ENTRYPOINT`/`CMD`.  For pure debugging, getting a debugging shell on a partially built image might be easier (for example, [How do I Run Docker cmds Exactly Like in a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393971/how-do-i-run-docker-cmds-exactly-like-in-a-dockerfile/45394090#45394090)).